# what's wrong with my grep command?

Tags: grep

Grep works when I use is with `ls |` but when I try the command by itself, it just gives me a blinking cursor that never goes away on the next line (as if it's running a command).

For example, I tried:

```
ls | grep zip
```

while in the `bin` directory and got a list of files, but plain `grep zip` in the same directory gives me the problem stated above.

Comment: sorry, ill include this with the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1.html) (emphasis mine):

```
grep  searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files are
named, or if a single hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines
containing  a  match to the given PATTERN.  By default, grep prints the
matching lines.
```

If you ran `grep` without a filename, or a pipe (the `|` in `ls | grep`):

```
grep foo
```

The standard input is the terminal - i.e., you. You have to provide the input which `grep` will search.

```
$ grep foo
this is me typing stuff
now I'm typing foo, which will get printed again because grep matched foo     
now I'm typing foo, which will get printed again because grep matched foo
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` takes a file or (files) as its input, when no file name is given `grep` reads from standard input (file descriptor 0).

When you do `ls | grep 'something'`, you are redirecting `ls` command's standard output to `grep` standard input via pipe (that's what `|` does).

While in the later case when you just do `grep 'something'`, there no file name given and hence `grep` will read its STDIN for input, no pipe is involved here so you need to type something on the STDIN (give input) to see the output.

**Example:**

```
% grep 46
245
480
460
460
```

As you can see `grep` matched `46` from my typed contents and showed it on STDOUT. BTW to close the interactive input session, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> which indicates EOF (End of File) (in this case read it as "End of Input").

Comment: i suppose grep is supposed to be used to search a file for content if it needs input from a file, however, weirdly enough, i tried making a file called test.txt and just typed in a bunch of random lower case letters, then used "grep test.txt *[[:lower:]]", and instead it displayed all the folders in the directory, without listing any of the other files that were in there

Answer (score 0):

grep is not using for finding files in linux. You can use find command for searching files. grep command can be used to search text inside of the files.

If you want to find files named zip inside of the /bin directory use below find command
find /bin -name "*zip*"

i used * infront of and ath the end, since the files there can be as gunzip, bzip, gzip. So to search everything matches zip word i used *.

Please read below two articles on how to use grep command and find command seperately. It would be more useful.
https://screwlinux.com/how-to-use-grep-command-in-linux/
https://screwlinux.com/find-command-in-linux-with-examples/
Thank you.