# grep without FILE parameter

Tags: command-line, bash, 20.04, grep

What happens when FILE parameter is not given in `grep`

```
ls
folder1 folder2 new.txt new.cpp folder3 # -> folder 3 has all .cpp files with main
grep -rl -e "int main"
new.cpp
folder3/one.cpp
folder3/two.cpp
```

From [`grep` man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/grep.1.html)

> If no FILE is given, recursive searches examine the working directory

But if i removed `-r` it doesn't give any output and still running like infinite loop

```
grep -l -e "int main"
```

From man pages it;s already recursive if there's no FILE parameter but if `-r` is removed nothing's happening. I'm a beginner what am i missing?

Comment: If you don't have the -r option, it's not running in an infinite loop, it's waiting for you to provide that stream (ie. STDIN  [*standard input*] has become the input, or keyboard) and it'll continue it's task until it reaches the EOF (^D) character.   You've made yourself (keyboard) the input stream (STDIN)

Comment: From [the man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html#DESCRIPTION): "If no *FILE* is given, recursive searches examine the working directory, and nonrecursive searches read standard input."

Comment: @GordonDavisson write it up as an answer (please use a Ubuntu man page though; then I'll upvote)   *the OP used the bionic manpage, even though tagged release was focal, so either is good*

Comment: @guiverc Will change the link to 20.04LTS

Comment: dupe: https://askubuntu.com/q/726076

Comment: @sudorm-rf Using the `-l` (list matching file(s)) option doesn't make much sense when you're not searching files, so you generally wouldn't use that option when searching stdin. It might make sense when searching files *and* stdin, as in `somecommand | grep -l pattern - file1 file2`. Here the `-` explicitly means it should search stdin, and in this case it'll print "(standard input)" if stdin matches, "file1" if file1 matches, and "file2" if file2 matches.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you it makes sense now. I didnot understand what this line means from man pages "`If no FILE is given, recursive searches examine  the working directory, and nonrecursive searches read standard input.` What exactly is meant by *recursive searches examine  the working directory*??

Comment: @sudorm-rf It means that if the `-r` option (recursive search) is specified, it examines the working directory; if `-r` is *not* specified (so it's *not* doing a recursive search), then it searches standard input.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you it makes complete sense. Thanks a ton. This question is closed unfortunately orelse you could canonical answer here. May be add it to the linked question?

Comment: @sudorm-rf have a look at Gordon's other answers/questions, and if you like/feel they're valuable, upvote some of them.

Comment: @guiverc Sure will do but my rep's still 11. Will do once I get to 15 for both of you. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @sudorm-rfI think it's ok to just leave my comments on this question -- they mostly relate to the `-r` and `-l` options, which aren't part of the linked duplicate.